# Django admin Password WEAK or STRONG message on successful submission of form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I need to display whether password entered while creating a new user in Django admin is strong or weak. Please help me here by suggesting how to do it. Any help would be appericiated

```
            class NewForm(forms.Form):


                email = forms.EmailField()
                password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
                confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

                def clean_new_password1(self):
                    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

                    if len(password1) < 6:
                        "display password is weak on successfully submission of form"
                    else:
                        "display password is strong on successfully submission of form"
                    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) included in Django to do so. I've yet to have the pleasure to tinker with it but it sure seems like it is suited for the job.

Although it doesn't directly answer your question, you could also try out [this module](http://thegoods.aj7may.com/django-password-strength/) which seems pretty(ier) to me but might not be exactly what you're looking for.